# Characterising groups of squarefree order.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Is there any interesting characterisation for finite groups of order $p_1p_2 \cdots p_n$, where $p_1,p_2, \cdots, p_n$ are distinct primes ?

For the simplest possible case of one prime, it is clear that any such group is cyclic.

For groups of order $pq$ where $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes with $p<q$, we have two cases that classify all groups of this order using Sylow theorem. This involves a congruence relation namely $p \mid q-1$ or not.

For groups or order $pqr$, we have using Sylow theorem that, such groups cannot be simple. I would like to know more on the cases involving product of 4 or more primes.

Does any congruence relation come into the picture while thinking about this idea in the general case?

One trivial observation I can see is that by fundamental theorem, if a group of order $p_1p_2 \cdots p_n$ is abelian, then it is cyclic.

Comment: We have only the cyclic group iff there are no two prime factors $p,q$ with $p\mid q-1$. In general , we have exactly one abelian group (upto isomorphhism) with such an order , namely the cyclic group.

Comment: Actually , there is a formula for the number of groups upto ismorphism for squarefree order.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1033467/589