# Reference enumerating groups of order a product of five distinct primes.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request, finite-groups, groups-enumeration

I found [this](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2371388) paper enumerating the groups of order $pqrs$ up to isomorphism.

I'm struggling to find one for $pqrst$. Has anyone done it? Could someone provide me with a reference if so?

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4824490/characterising-groups-of-squarefree-order) from yesterday, and the solution [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1032936/groups-of-order-n/1033467#1033467) for order $p_1p_2\cdots p_n$, for distinct primes $p_i$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0747717107000144) paper of Michael C. Slattery describes how to enumerate the groups of any square-free order. I do not know whether the special case of five distinct primes had been considered separately, perhaps earlier.

Comment: Anyway, the formula is very nice and can be used here (see the duplicate): $$f(n)=\sum_{m \mid n}\prod_p \frac{p^{c(p)}-1}{p-1}$$